# Move Search Service to Production Environment in SharePoint 2010

Tags: enterprise-search

I need to move my Search Service configurations from my development environment to Production (Scopes, Metadata Properties, etc).

What is the best approach to do this, PowerShell, backup restore databases?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I would use powershell for that. Configure everything with it and you can easily recreate sites/settings.

Best practice is to store the configuration in a xml.